# Magento possible SQL injection?

Tags: sql, magento, sql-injection

I've been having a few random search queries coming up in the popular search terms on a Magento site, the site has also been up and down like a Yo-Yo recently.

Could anyone shed some light on some, or all, of these search terms;

```
1)))) and benchmark(100000000,HEX(999999)) --

1 and benchmark(100000000,HEX(999999)) #

x Content-Length: 0 HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 18 <html>saint</html>

saint<!--#echo var="HTTP_USER_AGENT"-->

1 waitfor delay '0:0:6' /*

x;id|

<script>alert('SAINTL2NhdGFsb2dzZWFyY2gvcmVzdWx0L2luZGV4LyBx')</script>

christmas<script>alert("XSS");</script>
```

Comment: This could very easily be from one of the automatic security testing systems like webscarab or skipfish. If you want to take a look, the direct-to-boot linux distribution Backtrack delivers some of those, ready to go. If your installation is susceptible to many of the errors (especially injections), you can easily test yourself with these tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These terms are used (among thousands others) to test your site against various vulnerabilities. The presence of these markers doesn't mean your site is vulnerable. It means that your site being probed for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think it's related to a security scan the client had done on their website.